# How to do update and insert record from local to remote database

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have to do records update and insertion offline.
How can I import updated records without making duplication and also update existing records?

Will my following command work?

> > > cat newly_updated_data.sql | /usr/bin/mysql -u root --password=xxx DBNAME

Answer (score 0):

Only if the INSERT commands have an "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" clause and, of course, each record has a unique key.

This will make MySQL create a new record if one with the specified key does not exist. If a record with the given key is found, the "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" clause will execute and the specified fields will be updated.

Bottom line: in general, you cannot reapply the SQL commands and expect no duplicates.

Comment: I do have unique key to prevent duplication . How do I apply the updates for the existing records through command line ? As I mentioned in the post? Thank you so much

Comment: You cannot do this without modifying the SQL code in the `.sql` file. What you can do is run the script to insert the data to a *new* empty table. Then write a single `INSERT INTO table SELECT FROM newtable ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field1=VALUES(field1), field2=VALUES(field2),...`

Comment: I see. That means I could NOT achieve this within the dumped data. That's sounds not good! But thank you so so much!

Comment: If you can control the mysqldump command you can take a look at   `--insert-ignore` and `--replace` options. These will generate SQL INSERT statements that either ignore duplicates (i.e., the duplicate will be ignored and the existing row left untouched) or replace the existing line with the new line in the sql file.